# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined while deploying Next.Js app in Vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I am having the error `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` while trying to deploy my Next.JS app in Vercel.

```
const NewReserve: React.FC = () => {
  const setValue = (key: string, value: string) => {
    return localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  };

  const getValue = (key: string) => {
    return JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(key));
  };

  const returnPersistentValue = (key: string) => {
    if (getValue(key) === "null") return "";
    else return getValue(key).replace('"', "").replace('"', "");
  };

...
```

I am pretty sure that the reason that makes me have this error is because the Vercel deploy system runs on the server-side, so, window and localStorage are both undefined, giving me this reference error.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `window` exists first:

```js
  const setValue = (key: string, value: string) => {
    return typeof window !== "undefined" ? localStorage.setItem(key, value) : undefined;
  };

  const getValue = (key: string) => {
    return typeof window !== "undefined" ?  JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(key)) : null;
  };
```